# React-navigation open screen out of bottomNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a bottomTabNavigator with some groups of screens:

```
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarTestID: 'homeMenuButton',
        tabBarIcon: TabItem('home'),
      },
    },
    Beneficios: {
      screen: AdvantageClub,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarTestID: 'beneficiosMenuButton',
        tabBarIcon: TabItem('loyalty'),
        tabBarLabel: 'Benefícios',
      },
    },
    Repom: {
      screen: RepomScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarTestID: 'saldoMenuButton',
        tabBarIcon: TabItem('attach-money'),
        tabBarLabel: 'Saldo',
      },
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarTestID: 'profileMenuButton',
        tabBarIcon: TabItem('person'),
        tabBarLabel: 'Perfil',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.blue.primary,
      inactiveTintColor: colors.blue.secondary,
      style: {
        height: 64,
        borderTopWidth: 0,
        paddingVertical: 0,
      },
      tabStyle: {
        paddingVertical: 8,
      },
    },
  },
);
```

Inside of "Beneficios" (screen: AdvantageClub) i have one StackNavigator:

```
const AdvantageClub = createStackNavigator(
  {
    WebView: AdvantageClubScreen,
    AdvantageClubSignUp: AdvantageClubSignUpScreen,
    AdvantageClubSignUpConfirm: AdvantageClubSignUpConfirmScreen,
    AdvantageClubTerms: AdvantageClubTermsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AdvantageClubSignUp',
    ...noHeader,
  },
);
```

I need to open this WebView (AdvantageClubScreen) out of my bottomTabNavigator, like a new window. When i use navigator.navigate('WebView') the bottom menu keeps on screen.

[image: bottom menu after navigate to WebView]

Comment: what version of react-navigation are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of react-navigation are you using ?

I guess it's the V4, then in your nested StackNavigator "AdvantageClub" you can use `tabBarVisible` property in `navigationOptions` with something like this :

```
AdvantageClub.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const routes = navigation.state.routes;
    const tabBarVisible = routes[routes.length -1].routeName === 'WebView'
    return {tabBarVisible};
};
```